applyMatrix4() to bufferGeometry vs Object3d
Basically I wanted to translate the position of the gizmo line along axis X. When setting the following configuration over the mesh, the translation does not work:
Original Gizmo mesh:

for (const key in gizmo.translate.children) {
    const giz = gizmo.translate.children[key];
    if (giz.name === "X") {
      if (count === 0) {
        console.log(giz);

        giz.applyMatrix4(
          new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
            -0.5,
            0,
            0
          )
        );
        giz.updateMatrix();
      }

      count++;
    }
  }

however, when applying the translation over the bufferGeometry, it works:
let count = 0;
  for (const key in gizmo.translate.children) {
    const giz = gizmo.translate.children[key];
    if (giz.name === "X") {
      //0 is the arrow body
      if (count === 0) {
        giz.geometry.applyMatrix4(
          new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
            -0.5,
            0,
            0
          )
        );
        // giz.updateMatrix();
        // giz.visible = false;
        // giz.layers.disable(0);
      }

      count++;
    }
  }


I'm confused about this, can someone make some clarifications about this behavior?
